# How do I decode QR type barcodes on my iPhone?

Tags: mac, iphone, scanner, barcode-scanner

I'm interested in Decoding and generating QR Type barcodes on my iPhone.  I think it would be easier to generate them on my PC/Mac but I would like suggestions on how this can be done please?

Comment: Is this programming related? Because if it is it's better suited for stackoverflow.

Comment: No, not really, it's more a user feature than a dev feature.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For decoding, this article seems pretty comprehensive: http://www.simonblog.com/2008/11/14/qr-code-reader-for-iphone-barcodes-zxing/

For generating them, this website (http://qrcode.kaywa.com/) does the trick, and will work on the iPhone or a desktop computer.

Answer (score 1):

[BeeTagg](http://www.beetagg.com/) is a free app for the iPhone, and has an associated [web-based generator](http://generator.beetagg.com/).

Answer (score 1):

I have OptiScan on my iPhone and in my opinion it is the best hands down! See http://blog.airsource.co.uk/index.php/what-is-optiscan/ for more information.

Comment: Oddly they didn't put this into the US store.